# Why is my .glb file not included in the dist/assets folder in react.js and three.js?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, vite, react-three-fiber

I have created an app in react.js with Vitejs, I have included a 3D model with Theejs (.glb file). When I use npm run dev my 3D model works perfectly without errors, but when I run npm run build the 3D model is not included in the dist/assets folder, only js, css and images files are included. How can I fix it? I feel that there is something wrong with the vite configuration as the paths are well placed.

This is my vite.config.js file

````
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  
  root: './',     
    build: { 
      chunkSizeWarningLimit: 3000,      
       outDir: 'dist',
            },     
    publicDir: 'assets' ,
    

})```




and this is how I am loading my model in the component
const { nodes } = useGLTF("public/portal.glb")
````

Answer (score 2):

You can use [explicit url import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#explicit-url-imports).

```
import modelSrc from 'model/yourmodel.glb?url';
```

then

```
const { nodes } = useGLTF(modelSrc);
```

The model file will be assigned in [outDir]/assets after build.