# Issues with npm run build and missing files

Tags: reactjs, build, vite, rollup, npm-build

Every time i try to do npm run build and and run preview the site fails to load and i end up with the set of errors below telling me it failed to load resources :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYnXR.jpg).
Although everything runs perfectly fine when i do npm run dev...

I've been trying to mess around with the build rollup config as suggested here on stack overflow but idont know exactly what else to do:[Vite - How do I use a wildcard in Rollupjs build.rollupOptions.external?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71552229/vite-how-do-i-use-a-wildcard-in-rollupjs-build-rollupoptions-external)

```
 build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes("node_modules")) {
            return id
              .toString()
              .split("node_modules/")[1]
              .split("/")[0]
              .toString();
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

I've also tried messing around with with the main.js file as it was suggested here as well but i still ended up with a missing file and despite only being one file (less than before!)the build preview never loaded all in all i feel pretty lost any help would be sincerely appreciated!

Heres some more details of my package.json:

```
"name": "testr",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },


  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.4",
    "glslify": "^7.1.1",
    "prettier": "3.0.2",
    "rollup": "^3.28.1",
    "vite": "^4.4.9"
  }
}
```

** file structure edit how im importing the glb files:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCXnW.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh1LF.png) **

ive also tried suggestions from here but with no luck..
[Reactjs missing files when running `npm run build`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68514874/reactjs-missing-files-when-running-npm-run-build)

Comment: How are you adding your `glb` files to vite/rollup?

Comment: im currently importing them from outside the source using r3f useGLTF..should the files be inside the src folder instead?

Comment: Does `vite` or `rollup` recognise `glb` files? If not, they are not going to be bundled

Comment: your right i don't think it did for some reason your question inspired me to look a bit deeper into this and i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541810/why-is-my-glb-file-not-included-in-the-dist-assets-folder-in-react-js-and-three and also added this to the config assetsInclude: ["**/*.glb"] but i still also have a problem with svgs and the custom local font import im currently using the package react-svg but i dont know if it convert svgs to components and if so how to do it i may use something else i dunno what yet

Comment: You can use `vite-plugin-svgr` plugin for svgs and `unplugin-fonts` for fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put all the files and static assets that i wasn't directly importing into the public folder this included all the files that were using imported using using useTexture in my react three fiber scene for example and i had to change the file names to something like this

```
./img/pp3front.jpg instead of this ./public/img/pp3front.jpg
```

All in all i don't think i've ever had fun dealing with file pathss :/